# Redirection doesn't work in Flask after a POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

When I post data to an url, I want to redirect to the same url with parameter 'filter=yes'. If this is only a pure get (without parameters), I want to display a table, but if it is a get with parameters, I want to display other data.

My code is below:

```
LIST_OFS = [] # global array

@app.route('/liste_ofs', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def liste_ofs():
    global LIST_OFS
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.args.get('filters'):
            filters_form = Liste_OFs_Filters_Form()
        else:
            filters_form = Liste_OFs_Filters_Form()
            LIST_OFS = []
            data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from " + T_OFS + " WHERE statut != 'Archivé' AND ral > 0 ORDER BY date_replanif ASC", db)
            for index, row in data.iterrows():
                LIST_OFS.append(OF(row, data.columns))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = request.get_json()
        filters_form = Liste_OFs_Filters_Form()
        LIST_OFS = []
        data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from " + T_OFS + " WHERE statut != 'Archivé' AND ral > 0 AND client in " + convert_list_to_mysql_criteria(r['t_clients']) + " AND technicite in " + convert_list_to_mysql_criteria(r['t_technicites']) + " ORDER BY date_replanif ASC", db)
        for index, row in data.iterrows():
            LIST_OFS.append(OF(row, data.columns))
        
        return redirect('/liste_ofs?filters=yes')
    
    return render_template('liste_ofs.html', list_ofs = LIST_OFS, filters_form = filters_form, search_form = search_form)
```

When I post and type 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/liste_ofs?filters=yes' into my browser, I works.
AND I can see in the console:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Dec/2020 12:47:31] "GET /liste_ofs?filters=yes HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

So, I don't understand why my redirection doesn't work and doesn't appear into my browser.

Thanks for your help, I am struggling for hours!

Comment: To redirect (or navigate in general) after an AJAX request, you need to manually call `window.location = "some/url";` in the success callback. Just like an AJAX GET request doesn't automatically show the result in the browser, redirecting on the server does nothing on its own.

Comment: That's it, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Chris G's comment:
To redirect (or navigate in general) after an AJAX request, you need to manually call window.location = "some/url"; in the success callback. Just like an AJAX GET request doesn't automatically show the result in the browser, redirecting on the server does nothing on its own.

Answer (score -1):

I see wrong you forgot to add url_for

```
from flask import url_for, redirect

LIST_OFS = [] # global array

@app.route('/liste_ofs', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def liste_ofs():
    global LIST_OFS
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.args.get('filters'):
            filters_form = Liste_OFs_Filters_Form()
        else:
            filters_form = Liste_OFs_Filters_Form()
            LIST_OFS = []
            data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from " + T_OFS + " WHERE statut != 'Archivé' AND ral > 0 ORDER BY date_replanif ASC", db)
            for index, row in data.iterrows():
                LIST_OFS.append(OF(row, data.columns))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        r = request.get_json()
        filters_form = Liste_OFs_Filters_Form()
        LIST_OFS = []
        data = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from " + T_OFS + " WHERE statut != 'Archivé' AND ral > 0 AND client in " + convert_list_to_mysql_criteria(r['t_clients']) + " AND technicite in " + convert_list_to_mysql_criteria(r['t_technicites']) + " ORDER BY date_replanif ASC", db)
        for index, row in data.iterrows():
            LIST_OFS.append(OF(row, data.columns))
        
        return redirect(url_for("name"), filters="yes")
    
    return render_template('liste_ofs.html', list_ofs = LIST_OFS, filters_form = filters_form, search_form = search_form)
```

Comment: I've tried before posting, but still doesn't work... Thanks for your help!